# Magento Cart layout change not sticking

Tags: magento

Sorry this is a novice question...

I have changed the layout of my magento cart to popup.html.

i have edited the checkout.xml to use popup.phtml... this is the code i have used in the checkout.xml....

```
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <label>Shopping Cart</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/popup.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
  </checkout_cart_index>
```

The problem is that everything was working fine... but i was making changes on the category page and suddenly the cart has stopped showing layout popup.phtml and has started showing 2 column-left and that too without the cart content.

i was making some changes to catalog.xml ... but cant see how it would override the display of checkout/cart

I have been banging my head around this for couple of hours now... Any suggestions as to where i should look to see whats overriding the popup.phtml completely and just displaying an empty two column layout with left column.

thanks..much appreciate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular file *generally* does not matter. What matters is the layout update handle, i.e. top level nodes *in* layout update XML, e.g. `default`, `catalog_category_layered`, `checkout_onepage_index`. It is these which "scope" your layout XML directives.

Comment: <p>in the above code somehow missed this line</p> <checkout_cart_index translate="label">...i have applied it to checkout_cart_index... in the checkout.xml. Further, i have not made any other alterations ... i think... neither to individual categories nor to products... sorry if i sound a little lost... but i am :-( ....